# Born in the U.S.A., but I have no SSN & I live in Canada. Must I file a U.S. income tax return each year?

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, non-resident, citizenship

I was told when I applied for my U.S. passport years ago that as long as I had never worked in the United States and did not have a SSN, then I did not have to file taxes. This is what the U.S. Consulate told me at the time.

I am now hearing that this is not the case.

As a U.S. citizen living in Canada, what am I supposed to be doing about U.S. income tax?

Answer (score 6):

As a U.S. citizen — regardless of how you became one, or where you currently live — you must file a U.S. income tax return each year. Your *worldwide income* must be declared on your U.S. income tax return.

I found [a document on the subject, "U.S. Citizens Living in Canada" [PDF],](http://www.bmo.com/pdf/nesbitt/USCitizensLivingInCanada_Eng%20-%20BMO%20NB.pdf) from BMO's full-service broker, BMO Nesbitt Burns. Here's a notable excerpt:

> **1) I am a US citizen living in Canada. What are my  income tax filing and reporting requirements?**
>
> **US Income Tax Returns** – A US citizen residing in  Canada should be filing a US individual income tax  return (Form 1040) to report
>   worldwide income on an  annual basis, in addition to the Canadian
>   income tax  return filed as a tax resident of Canada. Although income 
>   is reported in both Canada and the US, double taxation is  generally
>   mitigated through the use of foreign tax  credits. The foreign tax
>   credit mechanism allows for any  Canadian income tax paid to reduce
>   the amount of US  income tax otherwise payable on the income that is 
>   taxable on both the Canadian and US income tax returns.
>
> **FBAR Reporting** – In addition to the filing of annual US  income tax returns, there are a number of information  reporting requirements
>   for US citizens. One of the  requirements is a Report of Foreign Bank
>   and Financial  Accounts (FBAR), Form TD F 90-22.1, which must be 
>   filed if you have a financial interest (or signature  authority) in
>   one or more accounts in a foreign country  and the aggregate value of
>   those accounts exceeds  US$10,000.   While there are significant
>   penalties (in addition to  possible criminal prosecution) associated
>   with the  failure to file individual income tax returns and  complying
>   with the FBAR reporting requirements, the  IRS has indicated that
>   penalties may be waived if the  failure to file the FBAR or a US
>   individual tax return is  due to a reasonable cause.   Beginning in
>   2014, under the new Foreign Account Tax  Compliance Act (FATCA),
>   non-US financial institutions  will be required to identify and report
>   on accounts held  for US citizens.

The above information about a U.S. citizen's obligation to file was taken from page 1, but the document contains additional information relevant to U.S. citizens living in Canada, such as how RRSP, TFSA, and RESP accounts are treated, etc. I suggest you give it a read.

You should also seek the advice of a professional in Canada & U.S. cross-border taxation.

Answer (score 4):

You were told wrong. As a US citizen, you're expected to file your tax return regardless of where you live. If you're under filing obligations (income above the exemption+deduction level, basically), *or* if you claim treaty or other benefits (for example to exclude foreign earned income or RRSP) *or* you must file [form 8938](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-8938,-Statement-of-Foreign-Financial-Assets) or [FBAR](http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Report-of-Foreign-Bank-and-Financial-Accounts-FBAR) - you must file your tax return, even if no tax is due (for FBAR - see Schedule B at the bottom, there's a checkbox to check).

In addition you must file FBAR about all of your foreign accounts, if your aggregate balances are above $10K (USD) at any time during the year.

See here for more information: [IRS Publication 54](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p54/).

Comment: Surely he can't file without having a SSN, doesn't he?.

Comment: @s.brody says who? having or not having ssn has nothing to do with filing requirements. You cannot claim dependents without ssn, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Not only must you file, but in many countries you must declare your status as a "US person" to your bank for FATCA reporting.

Even with a US Passport you may have trouble entering if you are not squared off with the IRS.

Comment: IRS does not have any way to make _entering_ US difficult -- and wouldn't want to, since it increases their leverage. If you have Federal tax debt over $50k _assessed and delinquent_ (not very likely for an expatriate nonfiler) starting this year IRS will notify State who (probably) will deny, revoke, or suspend your passport, which in general prevents _leaving_ US to go elsewhere, but Canada is an exception; US citizens can enter Canade without (US) passport, see travel.SX.